# Adding scores to MongoDB aggregation using $switch

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to add a score to my mongodb aggregation, based on which value the `name` field matched on.

For example: if the `name` matches "sitt" exactly, the score is 100.
If the `name` matches /sitt/i, the score is 50.

Here's my code:

```
db.getCollection('tags').aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$or": [
        {
          "name": "sitt"
        },
        {
            "name": /sitt/i
        },
        {
            "name": /^sitt/i
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "name": 1,
      "score": {
        "$switch": {
          "branches": [
            {
              "case": {"name": "sitt"},
              "then": 100
            },
            {
              "case": {"name": /sitt/i},
              "then": 50
            }
          ],
          "default": 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

But the `score` always turns out to be 100. The statement is always true.

Are $switch cases only meant to be used on numerical values, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregation framework `$switch` case expressions have to be valid [aggregation expressions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#aggregation-expressions) that resolve to a boolean value. These expressions are evaluated within the aggregation pipeline and are different from the `$match` syntax used in queries. MongoDB 3.4 doesn't have a [string expression](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-string/) for regular expressions, so you have to be a bit creative.

Setting up some test data:

```
db.tags.insert([{name:"sitt"},{name:"siTt"},{name:"babysiTt"},{name:"sitter"}])
```

Using aggregation expressions equivalent to your original comparisons:

```
db.tags.aggregate([
  // Match candidates (note: an unanchored case-insensitive regex cannot use index effectively
  { "$match": {
       "name": /sitt/i,
  }},
  { "$project": {
      "_id"  : 0,
      "name" : 1,
      "score": {
        "$switch": {
          "branches": [
            // First, check for exact match
            {
              "case": {$eq: ["$name", "sitt"] },
              "then": 100
            },
            // Next, case-insensitive anchored substring
            // (since the following comparison would match this as well)
            {
              "case": {$eq: [{ $toLower: {$substrBytes: ["$name", 0, 4]}}, "sitt"]},
              "then": 50
            },
            // Finally, case-insensitive substring match
            {
              "case": {$indexOfCP: [{ $toLower:"$name"}, "sitt"]},
              "then": 25
            }
          ],
          "default": 0
        }
      }
  }},
  // Sort in descending order of relevance
  { $sort: { score: -1 } }
])
```

Results in:

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "name": "sitt",
      "score": 100
    },
    {
      "name": "siTt",
      "score": 50
    },
    {
      "name": "sitter",
      "score": 50
    },
    {
      "name": "babysiTt",
      "score": 25
    }
  ],
  "ok": 1
}
```

Note: upvote & watch [SERVER-11947: Add a regex expression to the aggregation language](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11947) in the MongoDB issue tracker if you are keen to see this feature added.

Comment: Thanks, that does work. And I upvoted the issue on jira, too.

Comment: @skerit Felix does raise a good point .. your `$match` condition can be simplified to `/sitt/i`. There is also a strong caveat on index usage for regex queries: an unanchored case-insensitive regex cannot use an index effectively. For more information on `$regex` queries and indexing,  see [Index Use](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use) in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `{"name": "sitt"}` always resolves to **true**. You should instead use the `**$eq**` operator to make it work.

also note that your `**$match**` stage can be simplified a lot as your 3 expressions are equivalent to

`{$match: {name: /sitt/i}}`

so your query becomes:

```
db.getCollection('tags').aggregate([
   {
      $match:{
         name:/sitt/i
      }
   },
   {
      $project:{
         name: 1,
         score:{
            $switch:{
               branches:[
                  {
                     case:{
                        $eq:[
                           "$name",
                           "sitt"
                        ]
                     },
                     then:100
                  }
               ],
               default:50
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

Comment: Using $eq with regular strings did work, but not with a regex (as @stennie said isn't possible atm)