# How to include real score for RegExP output?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Problem with MongoDB query for RegExP search:

I have created indexes based field on search text. This is the query for normal text search.

```
db.metaobject.find( {$text: { $search:"data"} },{score: { $meta: "textScore" }}).sort( { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } )
```

For normal text output, there is score attribute included with the existing score result.

But I am trying to use same approach for RegExP, but the score attribute in output is showing as 0.
Below is the query used for RegExP search.

```
db.metaobject.find({ "name": { $regex: /_cm/i }},{score: { $meta: "textScore" }}).sort( { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } )
```

Now I want to include real score for RegExP output instead of just 0. Is this feature possible in MongoDB?

Comment: The [`textScore` relevance value](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#text-operator-text-score) is only calculated for queries against  `text` indexes using language-specific stemming rules. Regular expressions use standard indexes and do not support any notion of stemming, scoring, or relevance: they only determine whether a value matches the given regular expression. If you have simple requirements for calculating scores you might be able to [Add scores using MongoDB aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45084952/1388319).